# Wireless will not work with an Intel 5100 wireless card

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I did a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install on my Sony Vaio laptop, which worked perfectly with 10.04. Now my wireless won't work. I have read just about every Q&A on the subject and I have tried different solutions, including the official troubleshooting guides.

My laptop is equipped with a Intel 5100 wireless device. Ubuntu recognizes the device and it's status is given as connected in nm-tool. I can ping the gateway, my own IP number and localhost. Rfkill shows no soft or hard blocks.

- I can ping 8.8.8.8. Average time is about 15ms.

Any ideas? I am just a few hours shy of reinstalling good old 10.04!

Comment: can you ping global dns servers? like google's `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Yes, I can ping 8.8.8.8. Average time is about 15ms.

Comment: so you are connected to internet and speed is also good. wi-fi device is working fine. problem is somewhere else, check the configs

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. However it was pointed out (on another forum) that the kernel has been updated and that I should look for an updated driver. My wifi is via a usb dongle so I got the update from Realtek's site.

Comment: As far as I am aware (= I can find on intel's site) there are no updated drivers for linux later than 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
    sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
    sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Does it help? If so, write a conf file:

```
    gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Add a new line:

```
    options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Proofread, save and close gedit.